# Медицинское разрешение на приложение

Tags: android, google-play, юридические-аспекты

Есть приложение для расчета дозы инсулина (диабет) на Android. Нужно ли получать медицинское разрешение на его распространение в России, в частности в российском сегменте GooglePlay?

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтоп, но вот всегда поражался смелости таких людей. Неужели вы не боитесь что что-то может подсчитаться не так и вам придётся нести за это ответственность в случае чего?

Comment: @temagr Есть небольшой страх. Тестирование приложения начал со своего брата (больного диабетом), перед этим попросил его тщательно проверять расчеты, как и всех пользователей я буду информировать дисклеймером. В приложении вроде все показатели соблюдены.

Comment: Каким способом рассчитывают дозу обычно, без приложения?

Comment: @tse на бумаге по формулам, сейчас конкретно не назову именно какие формулы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно постановлению **Правительства РФ от 16.04.2012 N 291** "[Положение о лицензировании медицинской деятельности](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_128742/0c7bf8d00f19dbae8d6d2053e9f9971b0b4f9a31/)" в [перечне работ (услуг), составляющих медицинскую деятельность](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_128742/05b53ab8b8003b02ed994dbc0a7902b962eeab5a/) нет ничего похожего на вашу деятельность. Это же просто автоматизация ручного подсчета, если правильно понимаю.